# Sonar 3.7.2: Read Timeout - Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties

Tags: sonarqube

My recent sonar analysis started failing with timeout issues.  I've seen threads about this issue with 3.6 versions, but I'm using version 3.7.2.  My analysis was working without issues for several months, it has started failing in the past couple days.  Is there a way to increase the timeout setting?

This happens to only one of my projects.  This project is a lot bigger than the others.  All other project analysis is working fine.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XX-XX: Can not execute Sonar: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=com.XX.XX.XX-XX-client:release-version1&dryRun=false: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XX-XX: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=com.xxx.ecommerce.xxx-xx-client:release-xxx&dryRun=false
    at org.sonar.maven.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=com.xxx.xxx.xxxx:xxx-xx-client:release-xxxx&dryRun=false
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.downloadSettings(ModuleSettings.java:81)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.addProjectProperties(ModuleSettings.java:76)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.init(ModuleSettings.java:62)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.<init>(ModuleSettings.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor131.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:677)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.addCoreComponents(ModuleScanContainer.java:74)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:61)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:187)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:182)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:175)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:173)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1485)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:272)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:88)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:690)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2300)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentEncoding(URLConnection.java:496)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:270)
    ... 81 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Any update on that one? Got it fixed?

Comment: Not fixed yet, but I found my root cause.  I hooked up appdynamics and noticed that the ldap search was taking over a minute which one cause sonar to timeout.  I've disabled my ldap for now and the issue has been resolved. I'll need to revisit my ldap setup one day when I have time.

Comment: On my side it was simply that sonar is crashing quite often. I still haven't figured out why, quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the issue is related to this ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4140